# Gutenberg update ParentBlock when innerBlock changes

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I have created a gutenberg Slider-Block and a child block called slide. I want to update the slider everytime when a slide gets updated. I use the componentDidUpdate() from the innerBlock (the slide) but I don't know how to access the parent from there.

Comment: You need to share your code for people to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can access the parent block by using the following code:

```
// Get child block ID
const parentClientId = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockHierarchyRootClientId( props.clientId );

// Get parent attributes using child block ID
// @see https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/9032
const { iconStyle, iconSize, iconColor } = select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockAttributes( parentClientId );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also building a Gutenberg slider and ran into a similar issue where the parent block doesn't re-render when a inner block is deleted.

The fix is to create a subscription to the inner blocks, like this (if using a functional component for the Edit component):

```
const innerBlocksIds = useSelect(() =>
    select("core/block-editor").getBlockOrder(clientId)
);
```

This will cause the parent block to re-render each time the list of slides changes, so I can then re-fetch the inner blocks using `useInnerBlocksProps` and re-build the slider.

This [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/406403/20551) on the WordPress StackExchange helped me come to this solution.